# Substract CALayer from another, blend?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation, calayer

On the following image, the blue circle is only for debug purpose. My goal is that every layer behind the blue circle should be transparent.I only want to keep visible what's outside the blue circle.

[image]

Here is the code written in swift :

```
    let croissantView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
    croissantView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    self.view.addSubview(croissantView)


    let radius = 50 as CGFloat
    let width = 50 as CGFloat

    let origin = CGPointMake(0, 100)
    let end = CGPointMake(100,100)
    let highAmplitude = CGPointMake(50,180)
    let lowAmplitude = CGPointMake(50,150)

    let quad = UIBezierPath()
    quad.moveToPoint(origin)
    quad.addQuadCurveToPoint(end, controlPoint: highAmplitude)
    quad.closePath()

    let quad2 = UIBezierPath()
    quad2.moveToPoint(origin)
    quad2.addQuadCurveToPoint(end, controlPoint: lowAmplitude)
    quad2.closePath()

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = quad.CGPath

    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    croissantView.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    let anim =  CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    anim.duration = 3
    anim.repeatCount = 20
    anim.fromValue = quad.CGPath
    anim.toValue = quad2.CGPath
    anim.autoreverses = true
    layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "animQuad")


    let animRotate =  CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    animRotate.duration = 5
    animRotate.repeatCount = 20
    animRotate.fromValue = 0
    animRotate.toValue = 360 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180
    croissantView.layer.addAnimation(animRotate, forKey: "animRotate")


    let circle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: croissantView.center, radius: 75, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180, clockwise: true);
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.path = circle.CGPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.opacity = 0.6
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

Thoughts

- Substract from Layer, don't know if feasible
- Blend, don't know how to do it with CALayer

Thanks !! :)

Comment: Have you looked at the [`mask` property of `CALayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things I would suggest.

1. Change your croissant view to a layer (not sure this was necessary, but this is what I did)
2. Create a CGPath for your circle shape that can have its mask inverted. You do this by wrapping an outer rect around your circle so that the path looks like this:

[image]

3. Set your fill rule on your circle shape layer to even-odd:

   ```
   circleLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
   ```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I adapted your code to attempt it and this is what I came up with. Your mileage may vary:

```
func applyMask() {

    let mainLayer = CALayer()
    mainLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
    mainLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 200.0)
    // Set the color for debugging
    mainLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(mainLayer)

    let radius = 50 as CGFloat
    let width = 50 as CGFloat

    let origin = CGPointMake(0, 100)
    let end = CGPointMake(100,100)
    let highAmplitude = CGPointMake(50,180)
    let lowAmplitude = CGPointMake(50,150)

    let quad = UIBezierPath()
    quad.moveToPoint(origin)
    quad.addQuadCurveToPoint(end, controlPoint: highAmplitude)
    quad.closePath()

    let quad2 = UIBezierPath()
    quad2.moveToPoint(origin)
    quad2.addQuadCurveToPoint(end, controlPoint: lowAmplitude)
    quad2.closePath()

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = quad.CGPath

    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    mainLayer.addSublayer(layer)

    let anim =  CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    anim.duration = 3
    anim.repeatCount = 20
    anim.fromValue = quad.CGPath
    anim.toValue = quad2.CGPath
    anim.autoreverses = true
    layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "animQuad")

    let animRotate =  CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    animRotate.duration = 5
    animRotate.repeatCount = 20
    animRotate.fromValue = 0
    animRotate.toValue = 360 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180
    mainLayer.addAnimation(animRotate, forKey: "animRotate")

    // Build a Circle CGPath
    var circlePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(circlePath, nil, CGRectInset(mainLayer.bounds, -20.0, -20.0))
    // Invert the mask by adding a bounding rectangle
    CGPathAddRect(circlePath, nil, CGRectInset(mainLayer.bounds, -100.0, -100.0))
    CGPathCloseSubpath(circlePath)

    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    circleLayer.opacity = 0.6
    // Use the even odd fill rule so that our path gets inverted
    circleLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    circleLayer.path = circlePath

    mainLayer.mask = circleLayer

    mainLayer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

Here's the project where I tried it out: https://github.com/perlmunger/SwiftVertedMask

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It's working perfectly! I'm goona play with it to be sure to understand everything.